# Value probability based on percentage

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way to extract a value based on a percentage?

**Value probability:**
Bad: 1%
Normal: 29%
Good: 70%

```
var move ["bad","normal","good"];
```

A simple conditional statement:

```
if (move == "bad") {
bad_move = "That's a bad move!";
} else if (move == "normal") {
normal_move = "Classic move!";
} else {
good_move = "Amazing move!";
}
```

Then, is PHP better than Javascript for this kind of problem?

Comment: what is with the rest of the missing probabilty to 100%?

Comment: *"is PHP better than Javascript for this kind of problem?"* - A JS solution is bad if someone disables JS. A: Use both methods; serverside won't fail you in any case.

Comment: Just edited the percentage, my mistake. They are still open because I didn't find a good solution yet. I will choose the closest one. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred -ii- :) Good question.

Comment: @Mlabuit I see.

Comment: Aside from the question, you do realize you have a syntax error in your javascript?

Comment: i like to simply make an array with 100 samples, where 70/100 are "good", 1 is bad, etc. then you can use an Array.random-type script to quickly get said values without many call-time operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that samples values with given probability percentages:

```js
function weightedSample(pairs) {
  const n = Math.random() * 100;
  const match = pairs.find(({value, probability}) => n <= probability);
  return match ? match.value : last(pairs).value;
}

function last(array) {
  return array[array.length - 1];
}

const result = weightedSample([
  {value: 'Bad', probability: 1},
  {value: 'Normal', probability: 29},
  {value: 'Good', probability: 70}
]);

console.log(result);
```

I can't say if PHP would be better. This kind of problem shouldn't be any more/less difficult in PHP. Which you should use (JS or PHP) really depends on whether or not the function should be run on the server or client.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a continuous check of the probability and the rest of the random number.

This function sets first the return value to the last possible index and iterates until the rest of the random value is smaller than the actual probability.

The probabilities have to sum to one.

```js
function getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities) {
    var r = Math.random(),
        index = probabilities.length - 1;

    probabilities.some(function (probability, i) {
        if (r < probability) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
        r -= probability;
    });
    return index;
}

var i,
    move = ["bad", "normal", "good"],
    probabilities = [0.01, 0.29, 0.7],
    count = {},
    index;

move.forEach(function (a) { count[a] = 0; });

for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    index = getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities);
    count[move[index]]++;
}

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```